# Bitmaps or Binary search tree

Tags: bitmap, binary-search-tree

Which is the following data structures be best suited for insertion, deletion, lookup, set intersection, union? Optimize time complexity.

1. Bitmaps
2. Binary search tree

Comment: binary search is better until some array length because bitmaps need some decoding encoding. binary search time can change, bitmap is constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Foreward

The question is ambiguous, so I will make some assumptions.

First we are trying to represent a **set** of numbers over the range [0 to M] where M is a reasonably small number like 100,000.

The BST can simply contain the elements that are in the set.

The Bitmap can just be M bits long, and a bit is set if the number at that position is in the set, if not, the number is not in the set. I will assume that a Bitmap has already been created of size M.

In this answer I consider [Self-Balancing Binary Search Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) and [Bitmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index)--for non-balancing BSTs you would have to deal with best case, average case, and worst cases for each operation.

## Operations and Complexity

### Insertion: Add n to the set.

- **BSTs** take O( log(n) ) time for insertion.
- **Bitmaps** requires a simple (OR 1) operation on the target bit, and doing a quick division and some shifts to put that 1 in the right place, still this stays O( 1 ).

### Deletion: Remove n from the set.

- **BSTs** find the element, then delete it, then rotate tree, so overall O( log(n) ).
- **Bitmaps** requires a simple (AND 0) operation on the target bit, and doing a quick division and some shifts to put that 1 in the right place, still this stays O( 1 ).

### Look-Up: Is n in the set?

- **BSTs** take O( log(n) ) to look up n.
- **Bitmaps** return the value of (AND 1) on the specific target bit, doing division and shifts to put the 1 in the right place, overall O( 1 ).

### Set Intersection: Here's 2 sets, which ones are the same.

- **BSTs**: Do in-order traversals of both BSTs in a kind-of-MergeSort style, if two elements are the same add that into the return BST.

  - Adding elements to the return BST in sorted order is bad for balancing, so you could modify this by doing an in-order traversal over half of the BSTs, and a reverse-order traversal over the last halfs of the bSTs, then add the intersecting elements from the forward-list and the reverse-list in alternating order.
  - Overall this is something like O( n*log(n) ) since adding all the elements to the return BST takes longer than traversing.
- **Bitmap**: Walk over both bitmaps, storing the ( AND ) of bytes (or say 32 bits at a time) and store it in the result location as a bitmap. O( M ) where M is the size of the range the bitmaps are initialized to.

### Set Union: Here's 2 sets, combine them.

- **BSTs**: create a new BST by adding all elements from BST1 and BST2 into it by doing a breadth-first traversal of BST1 and BST2 alternating between BST1 and BST2. If the element is already there, then don't add it again. Overall this is something like O( n * log(n) ).
- **Bitmap**: Same as set intersection, but use ( OR ) operation. O( M ) where M is the size of the range of the bitmaps.

## Ambiguities in the Question

- What are the items to be stored in these sets (numbers, objects)
- Are the Binary Search Trees to be analyzed Self-Balancing?
- Is this a set chosen from a reasonably small finite range? (i.e. can this be done with a Bitmap? )
- It is unclear what Optimize Time Complexity means, although it seems to mean "What is the lowest known Big-O (upper bound) for the average-case for this operation on this data structure?"

## Conclusion

Bitmaps are better than self-balancing-BSTs for just about all of these operation.

Downsides of inclusion/exclusion Bitmaps:

- You only store inclusion/exclusion, and don't store any data about that element.
- Only works on integers, or objects hashed to integers in a 1-to-1 fashion (If the hash function is reversible you can get the objects back out.)
- You must have a fixed range of elements, like integers 0 to 100,000.
- The fixed range must be reasonably small, like less than 100 Million.
- Union and Intersection depend on Range Size and not on number of elements represented.